# visual basic stop webService connection

Tags: vb6

I have in visual basic WebService connection code:

```
Dim webService As SchnittstelleRechte.Service1 = New SchnittstelleRechte.Service1
```

I want to stop this connection if it during more that 5 second. there are a possibility to do this??? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try to do so:

```
Dim webServiceSchnittstelle As SchnittstelleRechte.Service1
Dim HttpWReq As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(Url), HttpWebRequest)
Dim HttpWResp As HttpWebResponse = CType(HttpWReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

If Not IsNothing(HttpWResp) Or Not IsNothing(HttpWResp) Then
    webServiceSchnittstelle = New SchnittstelleRechte.Service1      
End If

HttpWResp.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do this:

```
 Dim webServiceSchnittstelle As SchnittstelleRechte.Service1
 'Dim number as integer = 1
 Public Sub WebServiceConnection()
    'While True
    '  number = number + 1
    'End While
    webServiceSchnittstelle = New SchnittstelleRechte.Service1
 End Sub



 Public Sub angGetSchnittstelle()
   ' Create a thread object
   Dim thread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf WebServiceConnection)
   ' Start the worker thread
   thread.Start()
   ' Wait 5 seconds on the main thread
   thread.Sleep(5000)
   ' Stop the worker thread
   thread.Abort()
 End Sub
```

you can also test it, uncomment 4 lines, but there are a problem, you will waite 5 second every time